# How to remove duplicate lines without creating empty lines in CSV file?

Tags: python, csv

CSV file:

```
a,b
a,c
a,d
a,b
a,a
```

Code widely recommended for removing duplicates:

```
import fileinput
seen = set()
for line in fileinput.FileInput('1.csv', inplace=1):
    if line in seen: continue

    seen.add(line)
    print(line)
```

Result obtained:

```
a,b

a,c

a,d

a,a
```

expected result:

```
a,b
a,c
a,d
a,a
```

What should I do to not create these lines during the process?

Comment: print(line, end="")?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The print function adds a new line at the end of each line, to change the behavior add the following argument like this.

```
import fileinput
seen = set()
for line in fileinput.FileInput('1.csv', inplace=1):
    if line in seen: continue

    seen.add(line)
    print(line,end='')
```

There are many other ways and other libraries you can use to achieve this, this post https://www.py4u.net/discuss/16763 covers the other methods quite well, you can go through all of them and see which one works the best for you.

Comment: Hi mate, do you know why in this csv data the code does not remove the duplicate values? Example: ```/international/south-america/south-american-games/2018---bolivia/s9322/,a
/international/south-america/sudamericano-u20-femenino/2020/final-round/r46097/,a
/international/south-america/south-american-games/2018---bolivia/s9322/,a```

Comment: you should post another question with the full csv file its a bit hard to see the context like this

Answer (score 1):

First why this happens is because you are reading a line which ends with `\n` and the `print()` function is also adding another `\n`. If you wish to print the distinct lines only, you can print them using `print(line, end='')`.

However, if you wish to remove duplicate rows, I recommend using `pandas` like:

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('1.csv')

# Removing duplicate rows: 
df = df.drop_duplicates()

# Saving after removing duplicates
df.to_csv('1_clean.csv', index=False)
```

Comment: Hi @aminrd Your option is adding numbers and a comma on each of the lines, why is this happening?

Comment: @ResultadosOficiais It is because there is an optional parameter `index` which by default is `True` in `pandas` which adds a row number, by setting it to `False` it doesn't add the new column. And the output in this example is saved in the csv file. The printing just print a summary of the dataframe

Comment: Ah ok mate, thanks for support! I'm sure this detail will be of importance for the next ones to search for this question, thanks for the addition in your answer!